# JSON Decoding from URL with JAVA

Tags: java, json, encoding

I'm using this piece of code to grab json from a url and decode the inputstream with UTF8

```
    try {
        InputStream is;
            is = new URL(url).openStream();
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      int cp;
      while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) cp);
        System.out.println(cp + "  " + ((char) cp));
      }
      JSONArray json = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
      return json;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
    }
```

When I run it on a website http://www.somewebsite.com/data.json
I get a bunch of jibberish

Here are the first two chars that I get back (3 and 65533)

31
65533  \ufffd

I understand the 65533 is a replacement character so I'm doing something wrong with encoding.

I tried uploading this same json text to another website

http://ex. www.someotherwebsite.com/abcd
It decodes fine.

I tried downloading both files and they are both UTF8. 
Is it because one is a .json file and the other one is not?

Comment: You should close your InputStream, i.e. `try (InputStream in = ...) { }`

Comment: I added is.close() at the end, but I see the incorrect characters from the beginning.

Comment: I won't fix that; it's just good practice. There isn't enough here to reproduce your bug, and I don't see an obvious mistake.

Comment: Could you get the first ~8 bytes (not characters) of the InputStream (not the reader)? It might be UTF-8, but if there's a BOM, it could cause something funny to happen.

Comment: Either the web server you are downloading json from is not sending it in UTF-8 encoding or your console code page is not UTF-8 that is why you see `\ufffd`

Answer (score 0):

Try this method `Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(your-data-in-string)`. Or if this String is in a servlet and you want to send it as a response, use setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8") with the `response` object .

Answer (score 0):

You are just converting the charset. If you are getting data from the url, you should check if the parameter is url encoded and decoded it before parsing the JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering, the json file was not utf-8.
I was trying to decode using utf-8 when it was gzip encoded.